# use instanceof keyword in a visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce, email-template

Im trying to use the instanceof keyword in a visualforce template. I would like to pull the MobilePhone field from the Related Owner record. This works when accessed in apex but is not working in the visualforce expression.

VF Page:

```
<messaging:emailTemplate subject="request {!relatedTo.Contact__r.Name}" recipientType="Contact" relatedToType="Reference_Request__c">
    <messaging:htmlEmailBody >
    <c:RGComponent refRefId="{!relatedTo.Id}" />
    </messaging:htmlEmailBody>
</messaging:emailTemplate>

RGComponent:
<apex:component access="global" controller="RGController">
    <apex:attribute name="refRefId" type="String" description="This is the Id of the account" assignTo="{!ref}" access="global" />
    <table class="table" width="50%" align="left">
        <tr valign="top"><td>Account Name:</td> <td>{!ref.Account__r.Name}</td></tr>
<tr><td>Request owner phone number:</td><td>{!ref.Owner.Phone}</td></tr>
        <tr valign="top"><td>Owner Mobile Phone</td> <td>{!IF((referenceReq.Owner instanceof User), referenceReq.Owner.MobilePhone, '')}"</td></tr>
    </table>
</apex:component>


RGController:
public class RGController {
    public String ref{get;set;}
    
    public Reference_Request__c referenceReq{
    get {
            referenceReq = [Select Id, Contact__r.email,Contact__r.Name,Account__r.Name
            TYPEOF Owner WHEN User THEN Id, Name, Email,Phone,MobilePhone WHEN Group THEN Id,Name ELSE Id,Name END
            from Reference_Request__c WHERE Owner.Type = 'User' limit 1];
            return referenceReq; 
        }
    set;
    }
}
```

1. {!ref.Owner.Phone} - works fine
2. {!IF((referenceReq.Owner instanceof User), referenceReq.Owner.MobilePhone, '')} - Does NOT Work.

anyone on here tried something similar and got it working?

the below works fine in apex but when im trying to use a similar function in VF it does not work.

```
List<Reference_Request__c> reqlist = [SELECT Id, Contact__r.Name, 
TYPEOF Owner
WHEN User THEN Id, Name, MobilePhone
WHEN Group THEN Id,Name
ELSE Id,Name
END
FROM Reference_Request__c WHERE Owner.Type = 'User'];

for (Reference_Request__c r: reqlist) {
    if (r.Owner instanceof User) {
        User u = r.Owner;
        System.debug('User:=>'+ r.Id + ':'+ u.Name +' : '+ u.MobilePhone);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`instanceOf` is strictly an Apex language feature. You can't use it in Visualforce. Owner is a [Name](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_name.htm) object, so you can use the `Type` field:

```
{!IF(referenceReq.Owner.Type='User',referenceReq.Owner['MobilePhone'],'')}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. that did it!